# vmware tools not compatible with teamcity plugin when installed on mac os

Tags: mac-osx, vmware-vsphere, vmware-tools

Trying to setup the teamcity vmware plugin and using it to launch a mac os agent, I get this error in the agent log file - `[2017-05-09 15:59:55,356]   INFO - .vmware.VMWarePropertiesReader - Unable to locate vmware-rpctool. Looks like not a VMWare VM or VWWare tools are not installed`

Looking in the plugins [code](https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-vmware-plugin/blob/ca02f89f42330be6826a4132d7ef7c6ffdd66d1c/cloud-vmware-agent/src/main/java/jetbrains/buildServer/clouds/vmware/VMWarePropertiesReader.java#L49) I see that it looks for the vmware-rpctool util in `/usr/sbin`. I've installed vmware tools 10.1.5 manually by downloading them from vmwares website and copying them into the guest machine. They were installed in `/Library/Application Support/VMWare Tools` and the file `vmware-rpctool` is nowhere to be found there.

I'm trying to understand if this is some error in the plugin or perhaps I've installed vmware-tools the wrong way. 
Is there a "correct" way to install vmware tools that would create vmware-rpctool in the library the plugin is looking at?

Comment: Are you sure this teamcity plugin supports OSX? what kind of Mac are you running ESXi on?

Comment: As to your fisrt question - I'm sure since the plugin takes mac into account in the code I've linked to, but it does seem the support is a bit flaky.

Comment: Had to check to get the answer to your second question - `Apple Inc. Xserve3,1`